# How to reproduce undefined method error for NilClass

Tags: ruby, null

I want to find out how to reproduce the following error in Ruby 1.9:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

It's my own interest. The following doesn't work for me:

```
a = nil
a[:key]
```

It produce the following error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

Comment: Hmm, I ran that exact same code under my copy (Ruby 1.9.3-p125) and I got the NoMethodError as expected instead of your message. Not sure what to make of this...

Comment: You're using Rails 3.0, that's where that exception message comes from (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb#L53), it went away in 3.1.

Comment: Now it seems as though your question is "how do I get Rails to spit out a Ruby error message that it swallows?"...  I doubt that's really what you're asking, so could you clarify in light of the comments you've received?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I've understand what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works on my machine (submitting an answer since I can't format the comments):

```
⇨ irb
1.9.3p194 :001 > a = nil
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :002 > a[:key]
  NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/bjc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: @odiszapc That's a Rails error, I believe... if you want the pure Ruby error, use pure Ruby ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I've understand what's happening